# Selecting one of a has_many relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

What is the preferred way of selecting a specific record out of a has_many relation for a specific model in Rails? (I'm using Rails 5.)

I have a model `User` and a model `Picture` which are related via the following code:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  # ...
end

class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  # ...
end
```

What I want to do is to allow a `User` to set a profile picture from the images associated with it, so I can call `@user.profile_picture` on a `User` object and retrieve the profile picture.

Comment: You'd need to store it in `User`, probably as `has_one` relation. You can call this relation `profile_picture` :)

Comment: So `has_one :profile_picture, as: :imageable`? How does this persist in the DB? Do I need to create a `ProfilePicture` model?

Comment: Yes, and don't forget the migration for this relation as well.

Comment: So to sum it up: `has_one :profile_picture` in `User` model.
New `ProfilePicture` model that `has_one :picture, as: :imageable` and `belongs_to :user`.
Is that all?

Comment: Yups! That sums it up.

Comment: Why use polymorphism if you are creating a simple one-to-one relationship between two known tables? Placing the foreign key column on the owning side (users) is far simpler and will allow effective joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an additional one-to-one relationship.

```
# create by running:
# rails g migration AddPrimaryPictureToUser
class AddPrimaryPictureToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :primary_picture_id, :integer
    add_index :users, :primary_picture_id
    add_foreign_key :users, :pictures, column: :primary_picture_id
  end
end
```

---

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  # This should be belongs_to and not has_one as the foreign key column is 
  # on the users table
  belongs_to :primary_picture, 
             class_name: 'Picture',
             optional: true
end


class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  has_one :primary_user, 
          foreign_key: 'primary_picture_id',
          class_name: 'User'
  # ...
end
```

The main reason to do it this way vs for example a boolean flag on the `pictures` table is that having a separate relationship makes it easy to join which is important for avoiding N+1 queries which is an issue if you are listing a bunch of users together with their primary image.

```
@users = User.includes(:primary_picture).all
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you review the solution suggested by the commenter above and tell me about the benefits/tradeoffs of each architecture?

Comment: Using polymorphism in this one-to-one relationship is a mistake since it will not allow you to do a direct join between users and their primary image. Using polymorphism also means you lose referential integrity since the relationship is not backed by a foreign key.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Why is `optional: true` only set in `User` and not `Picture`?

Comment: In Rails 5 the default for `belongs_to` was changed to `optional: false` which means that the model automatically validates the presence of the association - this is not the case for `has_one`.